# Can I listen to data changes constantly from service class when app is in closed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an application connected to a Firebase database which has a service class that listens to changes that occur to a particular child and prints out notifications when child changes.

The service is started after the user logs in and continues running when the app is closed.  My database however has rules to ensure only authenticated users can access data.  When the app is closed will the service maintain that the user is still logged in and that the Firebase user is not null?

If not how can I ensure that the while the service runs the user will still be logged in to allow the service class to continue listening to data changes even when the app is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User sign in is persistent until you explicitly sign them out with the provided API.  The SDK will take care of automatically refreshing the user's ID token.

User sign in is not immediately seen when a process starts up fresh.  You will need to use an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) to find out when the user credentials have been refreshed as needed.

Comment: Oh thank you. I had no idea it was persistent . So I should add authstate listener to the service class yes?

Comment: Anywhere you need to know the current user.